# Expanding linear-gradient background unaffected by div layout

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have the following code. When you click on it (excuse the on-the-fly, inline `onclick` - on my page it is more properly set up), the background expands to the right.

Unfortunately as I am using a `:before` with `display: inline-block`, it is affecting the layout of the text inside.

It also is being affected by the `padding` property I have on the box. I *could* solve this by setting a negative `margin: -16px` on the `:before` element however the height of the `:before` element goes off:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid teal;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 16px;
}

div:before {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5%;
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, lightblue 40%, white 0%);
  transition: .3s;
}

div.active:before {
  width: 200%;
  /* or 300% if you want the entire background to be "taken over" */
}
```

```html
<div onclick="this.classList.toggle('active')">
  <span>Hi! I'm text! nice to meet you!</span>
</div>
```

---

This is how I want it to look like (it looks fine here because there is no text to get in the way and no `padding` property - both of which I will need for my webpage):

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid teal;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:before {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5%;
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, lightblue 40%, white 0%);
  transition: .3s;
}

div.active:before {
  width: 200%;
  /* or 300% if you want the entire background to be "taken over" */
}
```

```html
<div onclick="this.classList.toggle('active')">
</div>
```

---

Does anyone know how to remove a `:before` from the layout of a box? Ideally without using `position` as on my page based on some parent items to the above box, `position` gets a bit "funky." But if it's the only solution then so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make the background on the main element and play with `background-size`

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid teal;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 16px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(130deg, lightblue 40%, white 0%);
  background-size:10% 100%;
  background-position:left;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:background 0.5s;
}


div.active{
  background-size:300% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="this.classList.toggle('active')">
  <span>Hi! I'm text! nice to meet you!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid teal;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}

div:before {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5%;
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, lightblue 40%, white 0%);
  transition: .3s;
  position:absolute;
}

div.active:before {
  width: 200%;
  /* or 300% if you want the entire background to be "taken over" */
}

div span{
  position:absolute;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="this.classList.toggle('active')">
  <span>Hi! I'm text! nice to meet you!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fix this without either removing the `:before` or using position is by adding the text to the `content` property of the `:before`,

that would result in code like:

```
HTML:
  <div onclick="this.classList.toggle('active')"></div>

CSS:
  div {
  border: 1px solid teal;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 16px;
  }

  div:before {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: "Hi! I'm text! nice to meet you!";
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, lightblue 5%, white 0%); /*Or whatever width you like*/
  transition: .3s;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 4;
  }

  div.active:before {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, lightblue 75%, white 0%); /*Or whatever width you like*/
  /* or 100% lightblue if you want the entire background to be "taken over" */
  }
```

But most accessibility hard- and software is incapable of handling a `:before` correctly.
So why not set the background on either the div or the span?

```
CSS:
  span {
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, lightblue 5%, white 0%); /*Or whatever width you like*/
  transition: .3s;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 4;
  }

  span.active {
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, lightblue 75%, white 0%); /*Or whatever width you like*/
  }
```

which results in the same background effect, with the text centered.